# How can I force WiFi connection to only use ipv4? 

Tags: 11.04, wireless, broadcom, ipv6

I have Broadcom `bcm43224 wifi card` with proprietary broadcom sta driver.
At home wifi connection works well, but in the office when I ping some resource there is a lot of loss packets and I cant browse websites.

I have tried another way to check internet connection - download file with wget.

`wget google.com` - very slow speed

`wget -4 google.com` - normal speed

So, it seems that the problem is with the `ipv6` configuration at the office, can I force my wifi connection to use only `ipv4` and completely ignore `ipv6` ?.

Comment: Is it slow only at first or slow for the whole download (maybe try something bigger than a webpage to test this)?

Comment: In first case I wait at least about 1 min for host resolving and file downloading, the second works much faster.

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can set using ipv6 in menu system -> preferences -> network connection. Choose which connection you want to use without ipv6, then click edit, go to tab ipv6 settings and choose method ignore.

( this doesnt cover situations when you have some ipv6 tunnel enabled )

Comment: the problem is that I already have 'Ignore' on ipv6 tab for my connection...

Comment: interesting... maybe link local will help, dunno, ipv6 working here just fine. maybe you can try this page 

http://www.webupd8.org/2010/05/how-to-disable-ipv6-in-ubuntu-1004.html

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it could be that you are using a DNS server that doesn't do very well with requests for an IPv6 address. Instead of just saying it doesn't know how to handle those requests, it waits for a very long time and then your computer retries again but asking for a IPv4 address the second time around.

An easy way to test this (using your example) is to run `dig a google.com` and `dig aaaa google.com`. If the 'dig aaaa' command take considerably longer, your computer is picking up a misbehaving DNS server from your office network's DHCP.

So, let's change to using a DNS server that handles those requests correctly instead of disabling IPv6 (which we should be migrating to soon). Go to the network manager, select your wireless connection, and click edit. Go to the IPv4 tab and for method pick 'Automatic (DHCP) Addresses Only'. In the DNS servers field put '4.2.2.2 4.2.2.4' and click Save. Reconnect to the connection and see if that speeds anything up.

Comment: I tried to use `dig` from your example and in both cases I got the same result 

`; <<>> DiG 9.7.3 <<>> aaaa google.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached`

Comment: @krasilich That's real weird. It would seem to indicate that you shouldn't be able to resolve (translate from google.com to addresses like 72.14.213.105) anything. You could still try the solution; it might fix both the original problem and the error you just got.